# Laravel 5 migration error 1045

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I am having the following error:
[image]

After following this guide:
http://tutsnare.com/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-laravel-5/

I changed my .env file in accordance with the guide but I'm still getting that error.  Does anyone else know how to solve this?  Also I am using a mac with MAMP on localhost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.env` file you need to set the database config values to match your database configuration. With your current settings you are trying to login to the database as the root user without a password.

You say that you're using MAMP and the default MySQL password under MAMP is `root`, so your `.env` should have these database values.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Obviously, you'll also need to make sure there is a database named `laravel`.

> NOTE: Don't run this configuration in a production environment or any environment where security is important. It's ok for development, but for a production server I would recommend giving Laravel its own database user, and only granting that user permissions for your `laravel` database.

Answer (score 1):

If you using MAMP you need to add some things.

In your `.env` add this..

```
DB_UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
DB_PORT=8889
```

If you changed your MAMP MySQL port change it here too.

Then in your `database.php` config add `unix_socket` and `port`..

```
'mysql' => [
    'unix_socket'   => env('DB_UNIX_SOCKET', ''),
    'port'          => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
],
```